# Not able to get the load history from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COPY_HISTORY

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Snowflake table which gets its data (via COPY INTO) from an S3 bucket. When I tried to run the below statement to check the load status, it didn't give any result.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COPY_HISTORY(TABLE_NAME=>'HourlyTransactionStaging', START_TIME=> DATEADD(DAY, -14, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())));
```

Instead, I got this error

Table DBNAME.STAGING.HOURLYTRANSACTIONSTAGING did not exist or was purged.

However, when I tried to run this, it ran and gave me the results as well.

```
select * from information_schema.load_history
Where
    Schema_name = 'STAGING'
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'HOURLYTRANSACTIONSTAGING';
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what the issue was. Apparently, TABLE_NAME parameter in the COPY_HISTORY function is case sensitive and I was providing the table name as per the conventions.

```
HourlyTransactionStaging --> HOURLYTRANSACTIONSTAGING
```

Comment: Btw, this is documented here: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/info-schema.html#considerations-for-replacing-show-commands-with-information-schema-views

Answer (score 0):

Glad you figured it out. Also you need to make sure that you're on the correct database / schema before running the query as below:

```
use schema your_db.schema;

select *
from table(information_schema.copy_history(table_name=>'table_name', start_time=> dateadd(hours, -1, current_timestamp())));
```